# How to read value from react-hook-form from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have following form base on [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com):

```jsx
function App() {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        errors,
        setError,
        clearError,
        formState: { isSubmitting }
    } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = data => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    };

    return (    
        <form className="App" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <label>Ethnicity</label>
            <SelectEthnicity/>

            <input disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit" />

        </form>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`SelectEthnicity` is just a wrapper component based on select as follows. I had to do it because it is very long select with many options.

```
export class SelectEthnicity extends Component {
    state = {

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select name="Selectethnicity">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="white">White</option>
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="multiracial">Multiracial</option>
                    <option value="european">European</option>
                    <option value="poles">Poles</option>
                    <option value="bashkirs">Bashkirs</option>
                    <option value="slavs">Slavs</option>
                    <option value="russian">Russian</option>
                    <option value="romani">Romani</option>
                    <option value="chechens">Chechens</option>
                    // didn't add all long option. 

                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SelectEthnicity
```

How can I get the selected option when the form is submitted from the App component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form), you have to `register` your inputs to bind it to your form. I would recommend passing the `form` to the `SelectEthnicity` component (or only the `register` method):

```
function App() {
  const form = useForm();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    setError,
    clearError,
    formState: { isSubmitting }
  } = form;
  const onSubmit = data => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (    
     <form className="App" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>Ethnicity</label>
        <SelectEthnicity form={form}/>

        <button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit" />
     </form>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Then register the input via props:

```
export class SelectEthnicity extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select name="Selectethnicity" ref={this.props.form.register({required: true})}>
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    // didn't add all long option. 
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SelectEthnicity
```

In your submit function you should now have the selected value.

Comment: also, how do I make SelectEthnicity field is required? So that I can catch an error if it is no selected.

Comment: I would recommend you reading the docs. I searched for a couple of seconds and found the [solution](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Applyvalidation). You can pass validation logic to the `register` method: `register({required: true})`

Comment: for standard html fields such as  textarea, input, select, etc I can add   <select name="gender" ref={register({ required: true })}> and form catch error if it is not slected. But for my component  SelectEthnicity if I add <SelectEthnicity form={form} ref={register({ required: true })} /> . The form doen't care if it is selected or not not.   That is waht I am asking. How to apply this to SelectEthnicity?

Comment: Try to add `disabled` and `selected` to your first option: `<option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help.

Comment: I think I understood you now. You have to put the register on the `select` not `SelectEthnicity`. I updated my post accordingly. If you want to put it on the `SelectEthnicity` component you have to do it like this: `<select name="Selectethnicity" ref={this.props.ref}>`

Comment: I was convinced that it will work. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. In my code, I tried as  <select name="selectethnicity" ref={this.props.form.register({required: true})}> . But the from doesn't care at all.

Comment: @oemera   Many thanks for sharing your codesandbox.  I've been trying to fully understand the whole `register` thing.  Your sample made this really clear.

Comment: Glad I could help :)